# How can I write a shell script to direct grep data into a date-based filename?

Tags: shell, grep, date, scripting, filenames

I basically want to do this:

```
grep 'example.com' www_log > example.com.YYYY-MM-DD-H:i:S.log
```

...with of course the filename being **example.com.2008-09-27-11:21:30.log**

I'd then put this in crontab to run daily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verbose method:

```
grep 'example.com' www_log > `date +example.com.%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.log`
```

The terse method:

```
grep 'example.com' www_log > `date +example.com.%F-%T.log`
```

Comment: I think the back ticks are appropriate in this example as they are more portable and probably more universally understood which is better from a maintainable systems perspective.  Although it's possible I'm missing the point of the link you posted since you didn't give any context.

Answer (score 5):

```
grep 'example.com' www_log > example.com.$(date +%F-%T).log
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, that I usually use:

```
grep 'example.com' www_log > example.com.`date +%F-%T`.log
```

---

Backticks  are a form of command substitution. Another form is to use $():

```
$(command)
```

which is the same as:

```
`command`
```

Comment: Wow, I must be a slower writer. When I started there was only one answer, with a quick answer.
When I finished, there is a new answer and the other one has been edited. Both happened with in the last 10 minutes.

Comment: @Martin the website you link to has no relevance.  
This is not a useless use of backticks.

I think what you might be saying, is that backticks have been superseed by $().
http://doc.async.com.br/abs-0.3/HTML/backticks.html

Comment: In classic C shell and classic Bourne shell, back-ticks are available and $(...) is not.  The new notation is better when available, not least because it is far easier to understand nested invocations.